# ¿Como insertar en dos tablas al mismo tiempo? comparten un campo en común

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Me gustaría saber si es posible pasarle valores a un trigger desde C#
ya que necesito insertar en dos tablas una en socios y otra en domicilios
ambas comparten el campo id_socio, utilizé un trigger de inserción
pero ahora la cuestión es, ¿se puede pasar valores a un trigger desde C# para que después de que inserte en la tabla socios inserte valores en la tabla de domicilio?

Comment: podrias utilizar un SP , Stored Procedure

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: puedes hacer un trigger que se dispare cuando se produzca un insert en una tabla y te insertara los registros en las dos tablas, es una solución mas fácil que puedo darte

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Si tienes un trigger listo, da igual que insertes desde C# o desde otro sitio, el trigger se va a disparar igual

Comment: @Pikoh: Sospecho que el problema no es tanto el que dispare o no el trigger, si no que el trigger no tenga acceso a los valores que necesite para insertar en la 2da tabla.  Por lo visto, el uso de un trigger parece una mala idea en este caso.

Comment: Como te han comentado otros, el uso de un SP estaría bien.  O porque no simplemente ejecutar los 2 inserts uno tras el otro, pero dentro de una misma transacción, para que los cambios se apliquen a la base de datos de forma atómica. En todo caso, agregar un ejemplo concreto a la pregunta sería útil para aclarar lo que buscas hacer en realidad.

Comment: @sstan es posible, tal vez no haya entendido bien lo que intenta hacer :)

Comment: @pikoh: muchas gracias hermano! lo que intento hacer es insertar en dos tablas diferentes yen las inserciones tomando los valores de los campos de ambas tablas desde un form en C#, y recien tambien me dijeron que con un SP es posible, aun soy nuevo, les agradezco mucho su tiempo y su ayuda, que tenga un buen dia!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los trigger no se pueden llamar desde C# debido a que estos son lo más parecidos a eventos en el SQL los cuales se lanzan cuando haces un insert, update, delete sobre la data de una tabla.

para llamar un procedimiento almacenado desde C#

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
        {
            //Inicializa el comando que se va a ejecutar
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("NombreProcedimiento", connection);

                //Se agregan los parámetros
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaNacimiento", fechaNacimiento);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                    try
                    {
                        //Se abre la conexión
                        cmd.Connection.Open();
                        //Se cargan los datos en el DataTable
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    catch (SqlException sqlEx)
                    {
                        string error = sqlEx.Message;
                        throw;
                    }


        }
```

Pero lógicamente cuando ejecutas el Procedure estarás insertando o actualizando o eliminando datos, por lo tanto se estará lanzando el trigger para determinado caso, por esta razón administrar dicha ejecución constituye la piedra base, pues un mal manejo podría llegar a saturar la memoria del servidor de bases de datos.

Recuerda que al insertar, se SQL server por debajo crea la tabla inserted y al eliminar deleted, para un update mediante estas dos tablas simula la operación de actualizado, como veras el update por debajo realmente no existe

Comment: Muchas gracias! ya lo comprendí mejor n.n

Comment: marca la respuesta como correcta si mi respuesta fue de ayuda asi es como se agradece aqui en el foro

Answer (score 0):

pues trabajar con trigger es bien pero hay ocaciones que no son controlables, te recomiendo trabajes con un SP y lo invoques desde c# algo asi:

```
CREATE PROC ActualizaDomicilio
 @id_socio INT
as
 BEGIN
   UPDATE socios s
   SET s.valor= d.valor
  WHERE s.id_socio = @id_socio;
 END
```

en c#

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring")) 
 { 
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("<ActualizaDomicilio>", conn); 
   cmd.CommandType = SqlCommandType.StoredProcedure; 

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", valor); 

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias!, recien me doy cuenta que los trigger no me funcionarian para ello, aun soy novato jeje, gracias nuevamente n.n